# find a, b and c such that the matrix is singular

Tags: matrices

I'm given matrix N by N

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\\ c & a & b & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\\ 0 & c & a & b & 0 &... & 0 \\\ ... & ... \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & c & a & b \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find such $a, b$ and $c$ so that the matrix is singular

---

What I tried:
Singularity means determinant is zero. Let determinant of the matrix be equal to $D_n$ where $n$ is the size of the matrix, in this case I derived the relation, by definition of determinants:

$D_n = a D_{n-1} - bc D_{n-2}$ - a homogenous difference equation of second order. I solved it under the conditions that $D_0 = a$ and $D_1 = a^2 - bc$. Unfortunately the answer for closed form of $D_n$ turned out to be rather complicated which lead me to believe that my approach is probably faulty.
Is there a possible different approach maybe? Thank you

Comment: do you know the method to write a closed formula for the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did for the equation I derived above, and my solution for $D_n$ turned out to be quite a monstrosity, which I couldn't simplify. If that is truly the answer (as in: "a, b and c are such that the equation <instert the monstrosity here> is satisfied") then sure, but I thought that maybe there is a more elegent solution with a succinct answer